# Create conference with no participants in Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-studio

I am using Twilio Studio and I have a flow where I ask user A if he wants to call with user B.

- In case user A clicks 1 (yes), **I want to create a conference and put user A inside this conference.**
- In case user A clicks 3 (no) he just continues in my Studio Flow.

In the case user A clicks 1 (yes),  then I proceed to call user B with the "Make Outgoing Call" widget and ask him if he wants to call with user A.

- In case user B clicks 1 (yes), I want to place him in the conference where user A is waiting.
- In case user B clicks 3 (no), I want him to continue with the flow, **and I want to move user A out of the conference and let him continue with the flow.**

I am currently using an "HTTP Request" widget to send a request to my server which updates the user's call flow to a conference. The obvious problem with this is that in case user B says no, he will not return to Twilio Studio.

The possible solutions I have in mind are:

1. Create an empty conference call before putting user A in it. And use the conference_sid in the "Connect Call To" widget for user A (and send it to B afterwards). **My problem here is that I'm unsure whether an empty conference can be created.**
2. In case an empty conference cannot be made, do step 1 but put myself in the conference. **Problem: I don't think it's possible to have to TO & FROM number the same.**
3. Use solution as mentioned in nr.2 but buy a second phone number that's only purpose is to return conferences with himself included. (need to make sure that if user A or B leaves, the conference shuts down). Call this second nbr with the first one.

I'm not sure if the first or second suggestion is even possible. And if not, is the 3rd a viable option, are there (better) alternatives for cost and/or simplicity?